# Commutativity of direct and inverse limits

Tags: category-theory, modules, abelian-groups

In exercise 5.34(iv) of Homological Algebra book by Rotman one is asked to prove that direct limits and inverse limits do not necessarily commute. I have two questions :

> 1.) Is it true that $\bigoplus \prod \mathbb{Z} \ncong \prod \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}$ (where the sum and product are over a countable index) ? How does one prove it ?

and

> 2.) How to find an example of a system $\{X_{i\alpha}\}$ such that $$\lim\limits_{{\rightarrow}_{i}} \lim\limits_{{\leftarrow}_{\alpha}} X_{i \alpha} \cong 
> \lim\limits_{{\leftarrow}_{\alpha}} \lim\limits_{{\rightarrow}_{i}} X_{i \alpha}$$ but no isomorphism exists which would make the diagram [image]
>   commute ?

I believe by saying that direct limits and inverse limits do not commute, Rotman means the requirement that no isomorphism making the above diagram commute exists. Am I understanding it correctly ? Thanks.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/808155/5191).

Comment: 1) Probably they are not isomorphic. But the argument will be much more involved than showing that the canonical map $\bigoplus \prod \to \prod \bigoplus$ is not an isomorphism (which is trivial). 2) Yes, there is a canonical morphism $\mathrm{colim} \, \lim \to \lim \, \mathrm{colim}$ and this doesn't have to be an isomorphism. Even if it is not an isomorphism, there may exist some "random" isomorphism. Your question asks for an example of this phenomenon. Probably this won't be so easy ... (it is definitely not answered in the question mentioned by Zhen Lin).

Comment: If you take the system $\{X_{i\alpha}\}$ of abelian groups indexed by $i,\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$, where $X_{i\alpha}=\mathbb{Z}$ unless $i=\alpha$, in which case $X_{ii}=0$, and where the maps in each row and column are the identity map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ except when they involve some diagonal term $X_{ii}$, then $\mathrm{colim} \, \lim \cong\mathbb{Z}\cong \lim \, \mathrm{colim}$ but the natural map $\mathrm{colim} \, \lim \to \lim \, \mathrm{colim}$ is the zero map.