# Direct limits and pullbacks

Tags: category-theory, c-star-algebras, limits-colimits

Suppose we have three directed sequences of $C^*$-algebras, say $(A_n,\varphi_n)$,$(B_n,\psi_n)$ and $(C_n,\theta_n)$ and $*$-homomorphisms $\alpha_n:A_n\rightarrow C_n$ and $\beta_n:B_n\rightarrow C_n$, then we can take the pullback $A_n\times_{C_n}B_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and can also take the direct limit, thus $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{A_n\times_{C_n}B_n}$. My question is: Does the following hold:
$$\lim_{\rightarrow}{A_n\times_{C_n}B_n}=\lim_{\rightarrow}{A_n}\times_{\lim_{\rightarrow}{C_n}}\lim_{\rightarrow}{B_n}$$
or in other words: do direct limits preserve pullbacks? From my point of view this does not hold in general but i can not find a good argument. Someone an idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: I know that this result holds for colimits/inverse limits.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion... Direct limits are colimits (like coproducts etc), inverse limits are limits (like products, pullbacks...). Which is it? [By this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808155/do-pullbacks-commute-with-filtered-limits-in-this-sense?rq=1) it is true for (inverse) limits. As you can see it's more difficult for colimits. It doesn't help that you simply wrote $\lim$ in your question -- is it $\varprojlim$ or $\varinjlim$?

Comment: If the statement is true, it's because of something very special about $C^*$ algebras, not because of general nonsense.

Comment: And what is the reason that this is true?

Comment: I'm not saying that it's true, I have no idea. But *if* it's true, it's because of some property of $C^*$ algebras, you can't just write diagrams and expect to solve the problem.

Comment: Oh okay that was a missunderstanding, sorry. Yes I think you can solve this alone with special properties, but I think that this is not true, but i don't know why ^^

Comment: @Opluoos35: Have you tried to prove it for usual algebras? There it *is* true.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: What is the reason that this is true for algebras?

Comment: Filtered colimits commute with finite limits in $\mathsf{Set}$ (this is a standard result, see for example Mac Lane's book - it is also a good exercise to see what's going on here!). It follows immediately that the same holds for every category of algebraic structures - since the forgetful functor creates directed colimits and all limits.

Comment: In particular, the answer is *yes* for $*$-algebras. In the case of C$^*$-algebras, pullbacks are created from the forgetful functor, but colimits are not created. If I remember correctly, one has to complete the underlying colimit, right? And this is what makes your question non-trivial and interesting.